# Parsing 'user' data from Twitter JSON data using Python

Tags: python, json, twitter

I'm trying to parse some Twitter data using Python to extract information within the 'user' field of tweets.  Below is my code, as well as the error I keep getting.  My goal is to print out the screen_name, # of followers, # of friends for each line in the dataset.  I'm sure this is a simple issue on my part, but any help is greatly appreciate.

***code***

import json
import sys

```
def main():


    for line in sys.stdin:
        line = line.strip()

        data = ''

        try:
            data = json.loads(line)
        except ValueError as detail:
           continue

        if not (isinstance(data, dict)):
            ## not a dictionary, skip
            pass
        elif 'delete' in data:
            ## a delete element, skip for now.
            pass
        elif 'user' not in data:
            ## bizarre userless edge case
            pass
        else:
            print "\t".join([
            data['user']['screen_name'],
            data['user']['followers_count'], 
            data['user']['friends_count']
            ])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

***error:***

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/titan/print_info_FAST.py", line 33, in <module>
    main()
File "/home/titan/print_info_FAST.py", line 29, in main
  data['user']['friends_count']
TypeError: sequence item 1: expected string or Unicode, int found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The join method expects a list of strings but your list contains integers, you need to parse the integers to strings, try this:

```
print "\t".join([
data['user']['screen_name'],
str(data['user']['followers_count']), 
str(data['user']['friends_count'])
])
```